# Identify Children's parallel universe story from mid 2000s?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, parallel-universe

I keep thinking about this book that I read in the early to mid 2000s. It was a children's book about a couple of kids- boy and girl? Sister and brother maybe?- who somehow get into a parallel fantasy universe and have some trials. I remember a villain who, at the time, reminded me a lot of Capricorn from Inkheart, but more inhuman. The fantasy land I remember being very vibrantly described.

It probably wasn't new when I read it, it wasn't very long but I remember it was a bit of a challenging read for me at the time!

I know this isn't a lot to go off, the biggest stand outs to me are the vibrant fantasy land and the villain who child-me compared to Capricorn.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a very common trope - brother and sister going to another world. I think we're going to need a few more details - any more plot details you can add? Cover? Author? Any little detail helps, even if it doesn't seem important.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: I don't think I have anything else- I was hoping to stir up some ideas and see if any of them clicked. Certainly not the end of the world if this isn't answered!

Comment: I have a tentative suggestion. I would feel silly about calling this an "Answer," but it is at least *possible* that you are thinking of *The Secret Country* by Pamela Dean. It was first published in 1985 and then re-released in 2003. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B001QWDRSI/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1

Answer (score 1):

Is it ***[Of Two Minds](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/607075)*** (1995) by Carol Matas and Perry Nodelman?

That whole [series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50706-minds) is about a prince and princess (not siblings) falling in and out of alternate or parallel universes.

> The complex plot follows the adventures of Lenora, a headstrong princess with the power to make anything she imagines real, and Coren, the shy prince chosen by her parents to be her husband. Trapped in a strange land and stripped of their powers (Coren had been able to read the thoughts not only of humans, but also of animals and objects), the two must work together to overthrow the tyrannical Hevak, restore harmony to the country, and return home safely.